# Display the map using Baidu API in Android

Tags: android

I want to display a map using `Baidu` API.

Does anyone have an idea on this. If so, can you please provide some sample application code?

Comment: check this slide http://www.slideshare.net/CatChen/baidu-map-api-introduction-5939794

Answer (score 5):

I have recently faced this question too. This answer is 2 years late but maybe someone can still use it later. The answer given by iDev is clearly focused on javascript, which does not answer the question that was about Android.

[Baidu offers an official "Hello BaiduMap" tutorial.](http://developer.baidu.com/map/wiki/index.php?title=androidsdk/guide/hellobaidumap) The explanations are in Chinese only but the code can still be useful if you don't read Chinese.

When adding the API_KEY  to your manifest you of course need to use your own key. I have described how to generate that [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27035244/1446479). The difference is that for a mobile key you need to enter the SHA1 fingerprint of the keystore you use to sign your app, followed by your app's packagename specified in your manifest.

Baidu also provides a sample project demonstrating many functionalities of their maps. When  [downloading the libraries](http://developer.baidu.com/map/index.php?title=androidsdk/sdkandev-download) select the second one (described as 包括类参考、示例代码、开发包[...]) which contains the sample project, ready for import into eclipse.

I have also asked and answered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27035969/1446479) about some more advanced baidu maps features if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

We can do it using the method described [here](http://api.map.baidu.com/api?v=1.3&callback=aCallbackMethod).

`aCallbackMethod` is optional. We use it to initialize markers and other stuff to display over the map.

You can also take a look at [this](http://forum.zkoss.org/question/50834/how-to-load-baidu-map-javascript/) page.