# How generate API Key for Baidu Maps

Tags: android, baidu, baidu-map

I started to migrate my Android app to Chinese Markets and I'm replacing Google Maps with Baidu Maps, but I have problems when try to create an API key for use it.

I followed the instructions that described in this previous StackOverflow question, [How can i generate an API key for Baidu China for an website store locator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26993440/how-can-i-generate-an-api-key-for-baidu-china-for-an-website-store-locator/27035244#27035244). But in 2017, Baidu's changed their flow to create an API Key, and they added a step called "百度地图开放平台开发者注册 / Baidu map open platform developer registration" where they request to the user, a chinese cell phone, that i haven't.

I'm searching in the internet for more information about that but I can't find anymore that I know. If someone can help me, you're welcome!.

PD: Sorry about my english, I'm taking english class but I didn't finish yet.

[New step Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tU2EM.png)

Comment: As far as I know you need a Chinese phone number in order to complete that registration form. I just completed it earlier today, with the aid of my client in China on his Chinese cell phone. You could always try just with a non-Chinese phone number, but I'm not sure if that will pass validation...

Answer (score -3):

You can get the ak from the action that create a new application and put your need properties in that. When you create successfully, you will get the ak in this page.

[image]