# how does baidu map api works?

Tags: security, baidu, baidu-map

I would like to understand how baidu maps api works ? is it like google maps api where api key can be publicly exposed but it will still work against a registered/whitelisted domain.

Can somebody point me to right documentation or help with above

Answer (score 0):

*Yes*, It works with a publicly exposed api key, and work only against whitelisted domain.

to generate an API key, you can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26993440/how-can-i-generate-an-api-key-for-baidu-china-for-an-website-store-locator)!