# android baidu map tutorial

Tags: android, location, baidu

I am building an android app using baidu map (because in China). Unfortunatly I don't speak chinese and didn't find any tutorial for english speakers about implementing baidu map and get the current location of the user.

[Display the map using Baidu API in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722746/display-the-map-using-baidu-api-in-android) this answer helped me but I didn't find the SHA1

http://developer.baidu.com/map/sdk-android.htm Here is baidu map API

Does anyone has found this kind of step by step tutorial ? Or maybe an openSource projects implementing Baidu map ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: you can try this link http://www.programering.com/a/MjN3cTMwATU.html

Comment: Open http://developer.baidu.com/map/wiki/index.php?title=androidsdk/guide/introduction in chrome with google translation enable. Their translated website is accurate just like default English lang.

Comment: Haha thank you, the first link is useful !